# How do I install postfix with MariaDB 10.1? ...Or mailserver...?

Tags: mysql, postfix, centos, mariadb

I'm using CentOS 7 x64. Log: There isn't mariadb-libs for 10.1, not that I'm aware of. There is MariaDB-compat which as I found out seems to provide the same functionality and I have it installed, but it still doesn't work.

End-goal: I'm looking to install a mailserver using as little resources as possible under Centos 7 x64 LEMP + MariaDB 10.1.

postfix                     x86_64                2:2.10.1-6.el7                     base

```
    2.4 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mariadb-libs                x86_64                1:5.5.37-1.el7_0                   updates                752 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total size: 3.2 M
Installed size: 17 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.37-1.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-server-10.1.0-1.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check which libraries postfix requires:

   ```
   rpm -q --requires postfix
   ```
2. Check which libraries that compat RPM provides:

   ```
   rpm -q --provides mariadb-compat # (please check the name)
   ```
3. If `compat` does provide what is needed, you can delete the 5.5. libs:

   ```
   sudo rpm -e mariadb-libs
   ```

   If that gives an error of unsatisfied references, bug the MariaDB people to provide a proper `compat` RPM.
4. If step 3 succeeded (without using `--force` or such!), you can install the RPMs of MariaDB 10.1

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `MariaDB-shared` first. It should statisfy all dependencies normally provided by `mariadb-libs`.